# Entity Framewrok 6.2.0 Table-Per-Hierarchy inheritance strange query generation when filter by type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a TPH for a project, configured it and everything works nice with EF 6, however I noticed one time the query that is generated when I filter by type:

```
var existingTransaction = ctx.Transactions.Where(tr => tr.BalanceId == 1 && ids.Contains(tr.ParticipationId) && tr is DepositTransaction);
```

This generates the folowing query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[TransactionType] AS [TransactionType], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[BalanceId] AS [BalanceId], 
[Extent1].[ParticipationId] AS [ParticipationId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[TransactionAmount] AS [TransactionAmount]
FROM [dbo].[Transactions] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[TransactionType] IN (1,2,4,3)) AND (1 = [Extent1].[BalanceId]) AND ([Extent1].[ParticipationId] IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) AND ([Extent1].[TransactionType] = 2)
```

Notice the part with the transaction type, it contains all the transaction types configured, although the query is semantically correct, it is strange.
When I remove the additional filters and leave only the filter by type:

```
var existingTransaction = ctx.Transactions.Where(tr => tr is DepositTransaction);
```

the query looks as expected:

```
SELECT 
'0X0X' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[BalanceId] AS [BalanceId], 
[Extent1].[ParticipationId] AS [ParticipationId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[TransactionAmount] AS [TransactionAmount]
FROM [dbo].[Transactions] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[TransactionType] = 2
```

So, why the first one is like that?